# Completely Disable Module - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, configuration, xml

I am trying to disable a Magento programatically.For just trying I added the following code to myadmin header.phtml.

```
    // Disable the module itself
$moduleName="Thycart_Customcheckout"
        $nodePath = "modules/$moduleName/active";
        if (Mage::helper('core/data')->isModuleEnabled($moduleName)) {
            Mage::getConfig()->setNode($nodePath, 'false', true);
            echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Thycart_Customcheckout')->active;            
        }

        // Disable its output as well (which was already loaded)
         $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";
         if (!Mage::getStoreConfig($outputPath)) {
             Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig($outputPath, true);
         }
```

On echoing

> Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Thycart_Customcheckout')->active;

is returning me its false but actualy the module is not getting disabled from xml.

Also tried

> Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig();

returned a

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Error.

Can someone please help to make the node active to false in config file .
Thanks.

Comment: From `app/etc/Namespace_Modulename.xml` you can do it. Open the file and set `active` to false. Or just rename the file to something like `Namespace_Modulename.xml_bak`.

Comment: Please read the qn.I need to make this happen programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I already had a controller, so I added the following protected function:

```
protected function _disableModule($moduleName) {
    // Disable the module itself
    $nodePath = "modules/$moduleName/active";
    if (Mage::helper('core/data')->isModuleEnabled($moduleName)) {
        Mage::getConfig()->setNode($nodePath, 'false', true);
    }

    // Disable its output as well (which was already loaded)
    $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig($outputPath)) {
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig($outputPath, true);
    }
}
```

and called it in my action before loading the layout:

```
$this->_disableModule('Namespace_Modulename');
```

In phtml, use below code.

```
    // Disable the module itself
    $nodePath = "modules/$moduleName/active";
    if (Mage::helper('core/data')->isModuleEnabled('Namespace_Modulename')) {
        Mage::getConfig()->setNode($nodePath, 'false', true);
    }

    // Disable its output as well (which was already loaded)
    $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/Namespace_Modulename";
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig($outputPath)) {
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig($outputPath, true);
    }
```

Comment: I added it in phtml so no need of action required i gues

Comment: Okay. I updated answer for it. Please check.

Comment: This is exactly I have tried and did not work